# Script to rename multiple files in current directory and subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

The script should recursively go through each file in the directory/subdirectories (skip any symbolic links) and do the following replacements in the file names:

- Multiple consecutive spaces with just one space
- Multiple consecutive _ with just one _
- One or more underscores followed by one or more spaces with just one underscore
- Underscore followed by a - with just underscore
- - followed by underscore with just underscore
- Multiple consecutive “.” with just one dot
- Make file suffixes all lower case (e.g. .PdF to .pdf this is an example only
- Remove characters like @ or $ or !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find` and perl `rename`:

Note: perl `rename` is also known as `file-rename`, `perl-rename`, or `prename` on various Linux distros. Not to be confused with the `rename` utility from `util-linux` which has completely different and incompatible capabilities and command-line options.

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  rename -n -0 '
    s/[\@\$!]//g;            # remove all @, $, and ! characters.

    # remove leading and trailing whitespace (if any) from filenames
    s/^\s+|\s*\z//sg;

    # change all runs of any whitespace to just one space
    s/\s+/ /sg;

    s/[- ]*([._])[- ]*/$1/g; # remove space(s) and - around _ and .

    s/\.\.+/./g;             # reduce multiple periods to just one
    s/__+/_/g;               # reduce multiple _ to just one
    s/_*\._*/./g;            # change _. and ._ to just .

    s=(\.[^./]*\z)=lc($1)=e; # lowercase filename suffixes
'
```

The third substitution replaces runs of one-or-more of any whitespace characters (including actual space characters, tabs, newlines, form feeds, etc) with a single space character.  IMO, even though it's more than what you asked for, replacing all the different kinds of whitespace characters in the filenames is probably more useful than just replacing space characters.  Change `\s+` to   `+` (two spaces and a `+`) if that's not what you want.

The fourth substitution (`s/[- ]*([_.])[- ]*/$1/g;`) assumes that you don't want any spaces or dashes before either `_` or `.`.  That's more than you asked for, but is easily changed if it's more than you actually want.

On a related note, the second-last substitution replaces `_.` and `._` with just `.`. This is so you don't end up with "ugly" filenames like `foo_.bar_._pdf`. Delete this line if you want filenames like this.

The `e` regex modifier in the last substitution causes the replacement to be evaluated as perl code - in this case, the `lc()` function, which lower-cases its input.

Note: rename's `-n` option makes this a dry-run, only showing what it would do. To actually rename the files, remove the `-n` or change it to `-v` for verbose output.

Also note, the multi-line rename script can be squeezed into one long, almost unreadable line if you want (if you delete the `#` comments), but the extra line-feeds and indentation make it easier to read and edit, both on the command line and in a script.

Finally, this assumes that when you said *"go through each file in the directory/subdirectories (skip any symbolic links)"* that you also wanted to exclude directories, device nodes, named pipes, sockets, etc from being renamed - i.e. rename only regular files.

If you wanted to rename matching directories too, you'd have to change `-type f` on the `find` command line to `\( -type f -o -type d \)`.

You can, of course, use whatever find predicates you like to refine the search.

Comment: When you rename files recursively you need to make sure you do it depth first (OK here though as you're only renaming regular files) and rename only the basename of the file.

Comment: When using `perl`'s `s` on filenames, you almost always want to add the `s` flag so `.` matches on newline as well (as newline is as valid a character as any in a file name and you already correctly used `-print0` / `-0` to account for that) and also want to use `\z` (matches at the end of the subject) instead of `$` (matches at the end of the subject *or before a newline at the end of the subject*) (shouldn't make a difference for the latter in this case).

Comment: Note that it does: `rename(./foo . . JPG, ./foo JPG)`

Comment: yes, i didn't test that case.  not a good idea to merge space, ., and _ into one substitution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility called [detox](https://detox.sourceforge.net/) that solves many of your issues. From the Web page:

- Removal or replacement of upper ASCII Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) characters (i.e. left facing and right facing double quotes). Whenever possible a replacement character will be used (i.e. an "A" will take the place of an "A" with an accent mark over it).
- Removal or replacement of UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters. This operates along the same line as the ISO 8859-1 translation, except the scope of Unicode is much larger.
- Removal or replacement of spaces and other potentially tricky characters, such as (, ), and @. Removal of any "-"s at the beginning of the filename.
- Removal or replacement of CGI escaped ASCII characters, i.e. %20 becomes " " (which then becomes "_").
- Trimming of excessive "_" and "-"s.
- Directory recursion, dry runs, verbose listings.
- It's designed with safety in mind. It won't overwrite to a file that already exists, and it doesn't touch special files normally (but it can be asked to).

Comment: Guess its student with homework so it need some code

Comment: @gapsf That's a strong possibility. It doesn't seem to me like a real-world problem that someone who needs to solve it would need help solving. And I don't know that a script that does all of these things in one pass is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${${${${${2//[@\$!]}//[ _]##/_}//.##/.}//[-_]#_[-_]#/_}/%(#m).[^.]#/$MATCH:l}'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry run when happy).

That's nesting a few `${param//pattern/replacemenet}` operators:

- `${2//[@\$!]}`: remove all `@` `$` `!`s in `$2` (the base names of the files). Doing it first as it may bring spaces, `_` or `-` together which we need to squeeze in subsequent steps.
- `${...//[ _]##/_}`: on the result of the above, replace sequences of one or more (`##`) spaces or underscores with `_`
- `${...//.##/.}`:  on the result of the above, replace sequences of one or more (`##`) `.`s with `.`
- `${...//[-_]#_[-_]#/_}`: on the result of the above: remove 0 or more (`#`) `_`s or `-`s on either side of any `_` with `_`.
- `${.../%(#m).[^.]#/$MATCH:l}`: replace a `.` followed by a sequence of non-`.`s at the end (`%`) with the same (`(#m)` makes the match available in `$MATCH` in the replacement) converted to lower case with the `:l` modifier.

`zmv` will process the directory depth first (leaves before the branch they're on) and perform the replacement, doing some sanity checks before commencing the renamings to make sure no data is lost.

For example, that'd do:

```
mv -- 'A _  - _  .. - b -c-d ..PDF' A_._b_c-d_.pdf
```